# Take a specific Line from an Arraylist and work with it

Tags: java

I have to make a Quiz where the program takes a random question from a text file. I have made the program  to take a question from the file but I don't know how to make it take it randomly.

Questions are formed like this:

```
How many countries are currently members of the United Nations?,A:190,B:191,C:192,D:193,D,d                         
The atmosphere is held to the earth by _?A:Atoms,B:Molecules,C:Pressure,D:Gravity,D,d
```

so I split them with ",", and the last 2 words are the answer.
I tried a lot of different ways but it is just out of my league.
So if i have 50 questions in the file for example it should take only 10 at random and it should not take the same question 2 times, which is even harder to do

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    try {

        String words[];
        int scorer=0;
        int scorew=0;

        Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("quiz_questions.txt");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(fr);

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (scan.hasNext()) 
        {
            list.add(scan.nextLine());

        }

        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){

            words=list.get(i).split(",");

            for(int j=0;j<words.length-2;j++){

                System.out.println(words[j]);
            }

            String ans=scanner.nextLine();

            if(words[5].equals(ans) || (words[6].equals(ans))){

                System.out.println("Antwort ist Richtig");              
                scorer++;           
            }

            else{
                System.out.println("Antwort ist Falsch");
                scorew++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Du hast " + scorer +" Fragen richtig beantwortet und "+ scorew + " Fragen falsch beantwortet");
        scan.close();
        scanner.close();
        
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Datei nicht gefunden bitte prufen");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: generate a random number in the range from 0 to the length of the list - 1.  Then use it as an index for the list.  Refer to the javadocs for `Random` and `List`.

Comment: *"... it is just out of my league."* - That's a very defeatist thing to say / think.

Comment: i will try, and I really am not that good yet

Comment: I assume you are a student and this is an assignment. Are there any limitations on how you can implement the program? Can you use all the classes in the JDK? What version of Java are you using?

Comment: Another option: [Collections.shuffle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)) and take the first n elements up to `size()`.

Comment: i have no limitations and using 18.0.1.1

Comment: Rather than representing each question and answer set as a string, consider defining a class `Question` with fields `String questionText`, `Map<Character, String> answers` and `char correctAnswer`.